# Asp.Net Core 2 + Google Cloud Storage download Memory Stream

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, memorystream

I'm working on an Asp.Net Core 2 Web Api and I have to make an endpoint to download the file. This file is not public, so I cannot use the `MediaLink` property of the google storage object. I'm using their [C# library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

In the piece of code you will see bellow `_storageClient` was created like this: `_storageClient = StorageClient.Create(cred);`. The client is working, just showing which class it is.

```
[HttpGet("DownloadFile/{clientId}/{fileId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile([FromRoute] long fileId, long clientId)
{
    // here there are a bunch of logic and permissions. Not relevant to the quest

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var obj = _storageClient.GetObject("bucket name here", "file.png");
        _storageClient.DownloadObject(obj, stream);

        var response = File(stream, obj.ContentType, "file.png"); // FileStreamResult
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }     
}
```

The variable `obj` comes OK. with all properties filled as expected. The `stream` seems to be filled properly. it has length and everything, but it returns me a 500 error that I cannot even catch.

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, maybe how I'm using memory stream but I can;t even catch the error.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

You're rewinding the stream, but before you've written anything to it - but you're *not* rewinding it afterwards. I'd expect that to result in an empty response rather than a 500 error, but I'd at least move the `stream.Position` call to after the download:

```
var obj = _storageClient.GetObject("bucket name here", "file.png");
_storageClient.DownloadObject(obj, stream);
stream.Position = 0;
```

Note that you don't need to fetch the object metadata before downloading it. You can just use:

```
_storageClient.DownloadObject("bucket name here", "file.png", stream);
stream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: one more non related question. I see that when I'm trying to download large files (400MB) it stops on 15mb and give me a network error. WOuld you know why?

Comment: @AndréLuiz: Not off-hand. I suggest you ask a new question with more details (e.g. whether you can reproduce this in a console app running locally).

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be like below.

```
[HttpGet("get-file")]
        public ActionResult GetFile()
        {
            var storageClient = ...;
            byte[] buffer;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                storageClient.DownloadObject("bucket name here"+"/my-file.jpg", memoryStream);
                buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            return File(buffer, "image/jpeg", "my-file.jpg");
        }
```